# Randomly assigning Values Row by Row that were entered into a Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a bit of code that randomly picks a thing from a list of entered things in a textbox, I have also been able to get the code to enter it into the first cell of a table, what I now want to do is assign all of the things entered in the textbox into each cell of the row, here is my code:

```js
 var rnd = function () {
  var loader, things;
  loader = document.getElementById('ajax-loader');
  loader.style.display = 'inline';
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function () {
   var thing;
   loader.style.display = 'none';
   thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = things[thing];
  }, 500);
 };
 
 // a little functionality for erin foley...

 // save the things the user entered
 document.getElementById('things').addEventListener('blur', function ( evt ) {
  window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked'] = this.value
 })

 // use the user’s saved things
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ( evt ) {
  var things = window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked']
  if ( things ) {
   document.getElementById('things').value = things
  }
 })
```

```css
 fieldset input {
  display: block;
 }
 #result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
 }
 #ajax-loader {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
 }

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
 }
 td,
 th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
     text-align: center
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B &amp; B</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Green</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  <fieldset>
   <label>
    <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
   </label>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
   <img id="ajax-loader" src="http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/random/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Picking...">
  </p>
 </form>
</td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
<td><div id="result"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: Even though an error shows the snippet still works.

Here is some code that does exactly what I want the above snippet to do:

```js
var round1 = ['Forrest Gump', 'Tim Thomas', 'Pamila Henryson', 'Lotus Hobbes', 'Jerry Sparks', 'Kenneth Ingham'];
var round2 = ['Cyril Willard', 'Gale Frank', 'Aveline Derricks', 'Darcey Bullock', 'Jaiden Deering', 'Glenn Benn'];
var round3 = ['George Washington', 'John Adams', 'Tom Jefferson', 'James Madison', 'James Monroe', 'John Quincy Adams'];
/* game is a multidimensional array. 
|  Each element is an array(sub-array).
|  Each sub-array is a row in a table.
|  Each element of a sub-array is a cell.
*/
var game = [round1, round2, round3];
// count will be incremented per click of button
var count = 0;

function rounds(n, obj) {
  
// Determine which sub-array to use
var array = obj[n - 1];
  
// Determine the specific <tr>
var row = 'tr:nth-of-type(' + n + ')';
 
// Reference each <td> cell of the <tr> row
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('tbody ' + row + ' td');
  
// Cell count
var x = 0;
  
// Separate each element of sub-array
array = array.slice(0);
  
// while loop establishes limits and iteration
while (array.length > 0 && x < cells.length) {

// Get a randomly generated number 
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

/* On each iteration...
|  ...insert the element of sub-array...
|  ...that was determined by a randomly...
|  ...generated index number.
*/
cells[x].innerHTML = array[randomIndex];

// Increment cell count
x++;

// Join all of the cells together in it's new order
array.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
 }
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <body>
<table id="example" class="display" align=center>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <th>Blue</th>
    <th>B &amp; B</th>
    <th>Gold</th>
    <th>Green</th>
    <th>Gryphons</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<div style="padding:25px" align=center>
<!-- This button's attribute event has a incremental counter, so each successive click will change the count parameter -->
<button type="button" onclick="count++;rounds(count, game)">Simulate to next round</button>

</div>
 </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple elements with same id result in your html which need to be changed. You can give all the div the class result and can use a function getDiv() like in below example to get the next empty div.

```js
var getDiv = function(){
  
  var optionCount = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
  var rightDiv = null;
  for(var i = 0; i < optionCount.length; i++)
  {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('result')[i].childNodes.length == 0)
    {
      rightDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('result')[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  return rightDiv;
  
}

var rnd = function () {
  var loader, things;
  loader = document.getElementById('ajax-loader');
  loader.style.display = 'inline';
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function () {
   var thing;
   loader.style.display = 'none';
   thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
            var elem = getDiv();
            if(elem !== null)
   elem.innerHTML = things[thing];
  }, 500);
 };
 
 // a little functionality for erin foley...

 // save the things the user entered
 document.getElementById('things').addEventListener('blur', function ( evt ) {
  window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked'] = this.value
 })

 // use the user’s saved things
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ( evt ) {
  var things = "";//window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked']
  if ( things ) {
   document.getElementById('things').value = things
  }
 })
```

```css
fieldset input {
  display: block;
 }
 #result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
 }
 #ajax-loader {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
 }

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
 }
 td,
 th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
     text-align: center
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B &amp; B</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Green</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  <fieldset>
   <label>
    <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
   </label>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
   <img id="ajax-loader" src="http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/random/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Picking...">
  </p>
 </form>
</td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
<td><div class="result"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to with the click of the button simulate it so that each cell in that row gets a different name?

Comment: If you do not want to repeat a name , then you can remove that name from the things array. Next time updated things array will be used to select a random name.